# Не могу сделать бэкап базы данных c удалённого сервера

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, резервное-копирование

Скачал бд со старого проекта (созданного не мной)
Залил к себе...всё работает и отображает на сайте, но
Попытался сделать mysqldump результат:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1449: "The user specified as a definer ('crm'@'%') does not exist" when using LOCK TABLES
```

До этого были проделаны такие команды:

```
CREATE DATABASE crm;
CREATE USER 'home'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'home'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Работаю с удалённым сервером дебиан 10. Может ли ошибка быть связана с тем что это не моя бд? И как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пользователя `'crm'@'%'` нет. А до этого был создан другой пользователь `'home'@'%'`

Comment: @TotalPusher можешь объяснить связь между этим?) Я просто вообще не понимаю какая тут связь)

Comment: единственное что знаю...на прошлом хосте где до этого лежала эта бд вроде как раз использовался пользователь crm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему...
Не знаю как так, но я уже создавал у себя юзера срм и не работало..решил ещё раз
Create user crm identifity by 'password';
flush privileges
и mysqldump заработал
До этого когда создавал давал ему ещё GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES, может это было ошибкой